# check if items are not in a keyvaluepair list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, keyvaluepair

I have a list of type `List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>`.  This list contains 8 items.  I also have a string `line`.  I'm trying to check if `line` does not contain a word from the `TKey` (string) and the `TValue` is false.

I'm not using a dictionary because `lst` could potentially contain duplicates.

This should be true if `line` does not contain any `TKey` where the corresponding `TValue` is false.

It seems that neither `Any` nor `All` are suiting my needs here:

```
if (lst.Any(x => !line.Contains(x.Key) && x.Value == false)
{
   // this is always true even if line does contain a TKey.
   // I'm not exactly sure why.
}

if (lst.All(x => !line.Contains(x.Key) && x.Value == false)
{
   // this is always false even if line does not contain a TKey.
   // I think it would only be true if line contained *every* TKey?
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to check that all words with `Value` of `false` are missing from the target `string` by filtering on the `p.Value`:

```
if (list.Where(p => !p.Value).All(w => !line.Contains(x.Key))) {
    ...
}
```

You could also fix your query:

```
if (lst.All(x => !line.Contains(x.Key) || x.Value) {
    ...
}
```

This requires that for each KVP at least one of the following were true:

- Line does not contain the key, or
- The value is `true`

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you

```
if (!lst.Any(x => line.Contains(x.Key) && !x.Value))
{
   //line does not contain any TKey where the corresponding TValue is false
}
```